# Ruby pass timestamp as argument while calling script

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script which accepts couple arguments and one of that argument is timestamp.

```
# Basically this timestamp is getting from database and I just use Time.now for testing purpose
local_timestamp = Time.now.utc   

#{name} #{id} {local_timestamp}"
runcmd = "/home/test.rb"

fork { exec(runcmd ) }
```

But when it runs the timestamp argument is not taken properly and it just taking `Mon` only.

I tried to pass this argument as `local_timestamp.to_s` also which produced the same error.

Comment: `exec` creates a new process that does not know anything about your currently executing program. You probably want to only use `fork` which copies the current context.

Comment: Why are you doing `fork`/`exec` instead of `system`?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap script arguments with spaces in quotes:

```
exec(%Q(/home/test.rb #{id} "#{local_timestamp}"))
```